# Diagnosing application connection leaks in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am investigating a connection leak in PostgreSQL and would like to gather some diagnostics.

In particular, I would like to associate some information with each connection I make and then be able to query it directly.

If I was designing this kind of thing in MS-SQL I would change my connection factory to execute an upsert against a diagnostics table after each connection is made, containing a [@@spid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535.aspx), backtrace and other diag information.

Then to diagnose what is happening I could query [sysprocesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) joining to my diagnostics table on spid. This would give me clean *application* backtraces associated with each connection.

How can I achieve something similar on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL forks a new process to handle each connection. You can get the PID of this process easily:

```
SELECT pg_backend_pid();
```

This corresponds to the process ID visible in standard administration tools (`top`, `ps`, etc.). You can terminate connections using standard tools too (`kill`) or, with the appropriate permissions, by saying `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)`.

A list of current sessions is also accessible in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

One last note: PIDs are guaranteed to be unique as of the time the query is run, but will be re-used by the operating system eventually. You can ensure uniqueness by pairing the PID with the `backend_start` column of `pg_stat_activity`. For that matter, you might as well lump that in with your logging:

```
INSERT INTO log_table (pid, backend_start, message, backtrace)
SELECT procpid, backend_start, 'my message', 'my backtrace'
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE procpid=pg_backend_pid();
```